# How to mock.patch a plain dictionary in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

How do I mock.patch a plain dictionary {} ?

I would like to check if the  headers is set to {'Content-Type': 'application/json’}.

```
def get(self):
    result = Spider.get_news_urls()
    for k, v in result.iteritems():
        response = requests.get(v)
        xml = response.text()
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        data = ''
        taskqueue.Task(url='/v1/worker', headers=headers, payload=json.dumps(data)).add(queue_name='itagnewstasks')
    return 'success', 200
```

The following unit test seems to successfully patch dict. But I have a {}, which I need to patch.

```
@mock.patch('__builtin__.dict')
@mock.patch('requests.get')
def test_header_is_set_to_json(self, req_get, x):
    gen = Generator()
    gen.get()
    x.assert_called_with()
```

I suppose an alternative way would be to mock patch `taskqueue.Task()` and compare if it was called with `headers= {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` as a parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The headers you seek to mock are constructed within the method you are testing, so mocking the `taskqueue.Task` call would be much easier. If you were passing the header dict into the method then you could just hold onto a copy and check that it has been updated as you expect.

You can use [patch.dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-dict) to mock a dictionary:

```
>>> foo = {}
>>> with patch.dict(foo, {'newkey': 'newvalue'}):
...     assert foo == {'newkey': 'newvalue'}
...
>>> assert foo == {}
```

Comment: note: it will reset the dict back to the original value for all keys, not just the ones you patched!

Answer (score -1):

Ran in to an issue with `patch.dict` today.

`patch.dict` rolls back the whole dict at `__exit__`... not just the patched values.   if this isn't the behavior you want, you might want to use a patcher that's more selective.

This works the same as `patch.dict`, but it only restores the keys you patched.

```
class DictPatch:
    def __init__(self, obj, patch):
        self.obj = obj
        self.patch = patch
        self.save = {}
        self.pop = []

    def start(self):
        self.save = {k: v for k, v in self.obj.items() if k in self.patch}
        self.pop = [k for k in self.patch if k not in self.obj]
        self.obj.update(self.patch)
        # this allows you to do self.addCleanup(DictPatch(...)), which is nice
        return self.stop

    def stop(self):
        self.obj.update(self.save)
        for k in self.pop:
            self.obj.pop(k)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.stop()
```